# How to get envelope link

Tags: python, docusignapi

In my application, after user register, it creates a docusign document and send in an envelope to user's email for signature.

My question is how do I also provide a link to the document from my application? I want it to be the same link that user would access in their email. I have tried to construct url from envelope_id which i get from the result of create_envelope, but that seems to be wrong. Is there actually a way to do this? Or the it has to be accessed from user's email?

An envelope uri: `envelopes/ids`

Comment: Answered below. If it was helpful, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow you might be looking for is called [Embedded Signing](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing). With embedded signing, you can redirect your users to sign DocuSign envelopes instead of having them sign via email.

Two steps process:

First, you will create your envelope. Be sure to include clientUserId for each recipient object. This will be used when you want to generate unique signing URLs in the next step.

```
POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Envelope with Embedded Signer",
    "documents": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "contract.pdf",
        "documentBase64": "base64 document bytes...",
    }],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "email": "john@email.com",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "clientUserId": "1234"
        }]
    }
}
```

Second, you will generate the RecipientViewURL for a given user.

```
POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient
{
    "userName": "John Doe",
    "email": "johndoe@email.com",
    "recipientId": "1",
    "clientUserId": "1234",
    "authenticationMethod": "email",
    "returnUrl": "https://www.docusign.com/devcenter"
}
```

[Here is a guide](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/embedding) that provides a more thorough background on the feature.

Comment: The resulting URL must be used within 5 minutes of your API call that obtains it. So you can't put this link on your web site. Instead, put a button that will *generate* the link for the user and redirect them immediately.